# Задать параметры для команды в cmd

Tags: cmd, консоль

Я получаю 3 параметра, которые в дальнейшем использую в программе. Это работает так, что я ввожу путь и жму Enter

```
path_text = input("Enter path to text file ")
path_pdf_first = input("Enter path to fist pdf file ")
path_pdf_second = input("Enter path to second pdf file ")
```

Как я могу указать 3 этих пути в качестве параметров в командной строке? Что-то типа

python test.py path1 path2 path3

Answer (score 0):

Параметры передаются через слеш
    python test.py /path1 /path2 /path3

Comment: А теперь внимательно прочитай вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
(echo cd & echo time /t) | cmd
```

Предположу что в твоём случае это будет

```
(echo path1 & echo path2 & echo path3) | python test.py
```

Comment: Не пойму, мне стоит занести весь мой код в функцию с параметрами в правильном порядке, а строчки из моего вопроса тогда убрать?

Comment: Нет, ничего в коде не менять.

Comment: Но если я просто напишу после python test.py 3 пути к файлам, то как программа поймет вместо каких переменных занести 3 этих пути?

Comment: Может всё-таки ответ прочитаешь? Или иди спрашивать в соседнем ответе, как менять скрипт.

Comment: Я прочитал и мне это ничего не дало. Вероятно, если бы ответ звучало недвусмысленно и, как любят говорить, эксперименто-направлено, то я бы с легкостью все сделал без лишних вопросов. Если не добьюсь ответа, то задам его еще раз, это так и должно работать